# No OpenGL in Processing 3

Tags: opengl, processing

There is no **OpenGL** library in `Sketch => Import Library` or in `Sketch => Import Library => Add Library` in **Processing 3**.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from **Processing 2.0**, **OpenGL** is a part of the core (https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/OpenGL-Issues).

So eg this:

```
void setup(){
  size(640, 480, OPENGL);
  bezier(20, 20, 50, 10, 80, 100, 30, 200);
}
```

should work right away.

Comment: You got it! Bare in mind OPENGL in Processing 3 is actually the P3D renderer, could simply use P3D directly ([source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PConstants.java#L67)). Be sure to also checkout the [PShader tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/)